# Simple form issue applying custom regexp (Rails 4)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, regex, simple-form

I'm having some issues validating fields in Rails using simple_form gem. The issue is that, when using a custom regexp in Rails to validate in the server, everything goes fine, but the javaScript takes the whole regexp (including the tags \A or \z so it appears like wrong. For example, my validation expression is:

```
validates_format_of [:field1, :field2], :with => /\A(myregexp)\z/i
```

But in the HTML code, is sent like this, so the JavaScript doesn't take the right expression:

```
pattern="\A(myregexp)\z"
```

I know that JavaScript doesn't accept \A or either \z, but also I can't use the old tags for rails ^ or $ cause it shows an error.

Any ideas of how can I fix this?

Comment: could you paste the error? I don't understand why `^` `$` would break anything.

Comment: I don't have an environment for Rails to test right now, but the issue was the same as this one: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/829 Anyway thanks for your answer :)